# get chef template path from template

Tags: chef, template

In my chef erb template, I want to get the path the template is being copied to. So it looks like like:

```
MY_PATH=<%= ###HOW DO I GET THE TEMPLATE PATH### %>
```

Is there a way to get that?

Comment: You could pass it in as a variable to the template, but I know of no way to devine it.  As I understand it, Chef is actually using a library to get a `string` from the ERB and then writing that to a file.

Comment: What @TejayCardon said. You don't want to have special logic in templates. It's like with web applications (MVC-Pattern). Because your template resource in chef needs a filename, you can easily extract the directory to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using a variable:

```
file = '/etc/whatever/app.conf'

template file do
  source 'app.conf.erb'
  variables(
    directory: ::File.dirname(file)
  )
  action :create
end
```

template:

```
 <%= @directory %>
```

which value will be: `/etc/whatever`